# Redux setState called after component unmounted

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm building a React/Redux app with 3 main Components -
Instructions, StoryFeed and Quiz which i'm trying to cycle through for
4 Rounds (3 + 1 practice).

I have a Clock Component (that's nested within the StoryFeed
Component) and it's set to move to the Quiz Component when the timer
hits zero. However, it seems to be calling setState after it's been
unmounted and giving the infinite error

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

I can't figure out how to prevent this. Here's the code below for the `Clock` Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import ReactInterval from 'react-interval'

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      timed: props.timed,
      counting: true
    }

    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this)
  }

  reset() {
    this.setState({
      counting: true,
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })

  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ counting: false }, () => this.props.complete())
  }
  tick() {
    const { count, timed, counting } = this.state
    if (count + 1 > timed && counting) {
      this.componentWillUnmount()
    } else {
      this.reset();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="clock alert alert-warning">
        <ReactInterval
          timeout={1000}
          enabled={this.props.timed > 1 && this.state.count < this.props.timed}
          callback={() => this.tick()}
        />
        <span>{this.state.timed - this.state.count}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Clock.propTypes = {
  timed: PropTypes.number,
  complete: PropTypes.func
}

export default Clock
```

And here's the parent Component `StoryFeed` code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Marquee from './Marquee'
import * as stories from '../stories'
import Clock from './Clock'
import { chunk, now } from '../utils'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class StoryFeed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: stories.example,
      currentTest: 1,
      count: 0,
      timed: props.timed,
      selected: []
    }
    this.storyLoad.bind(this)
    this.select = this.select.bind(this)
    this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add('mosaic-full-screen')
    this.storyLoad();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove('mosaic-full-screen')


  }

  select(id) {
    if (this.state.selected.find(s => s.id == id)) return

    this.setState({
      selected: [...this.state.selected, { id, time: now() }]
    })
  }

  isSelected(id) {
    return this.state.selected.find(j => j.id === id)
  }

  storyLoad(state) {
    switch (this.state.currentTest){
      case 1:
      this.setState({text: stories.example});
        console.log(this.state.currentTest)
      break;
      case 2:
      this.setState({text: stories.colleagues});
      break;
      case 3:
      this.setState({text: stories.aroomforthenight});
      break;
      case 4:
      this.setState({text: stories.thepromotion});
      break;
    }
  };



  reset() {
    this.clock &&
      this.clock.reset(4, () => {
        this.setState({
          counting: true
        })
      })
  }


  render() {
    const { enterAnswers, id, show, timed } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="story">
        <div className='container'>
          <Marquee text={this.state.text.join(' - ')} loop={false} hoverToStop={true} />
        </div>
        <div className="controls">
          {timed && (
            <Clock
              timed={timed}
              complete={() => enterAnswers(id, this.state.selected, now())}

            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      )
    }

}
StoryFeed.propTypes = {
  timed: PropTypes.number,

  enterAnswers: PropTypes.func,
  id: PropTypes.number,
  show: PropTypes.oneOf(['window', 'jigsaw'])
}
export default StoryFeed
```

The other answers to this question seem to be case specific

Comment: I find it interesting that you are calling `componentWillUnmount` yourself, this is however a react lifecycle event, that should be called by react just before unmouting the component. Do you know which component is throwing the warning? I wonder if it would be the component that renders the `StoryFeed` component or if it is really the `Clock` component

Comment: @Icepickle the reasoning behind this call to `componentWillUnmount` seems to be that the body itself (outside the React root node) is being modified when closing this component. Perfectly legitimate use of this lifecycle method!

Comment: @ZekeDroid Sure, ofcourse you can call it, however, I don't think it should be called, why not have an extra method that gets called from both the tick method as well as from the `componentWillUnmount` method? You also don't do it in your own answer, you just set a flag marking it as unmounted. So yeah, you can call it, does it improve readability or maintainability, no, I don't think so, cause it will always raise the same questions

Comment: Oh man I was so off in what you were talking about since I didn't read the whole code snippet! No, you're entirely correct and it should be its own method. User code shouldn't be calling lifecycle methods directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a method attribute on unmount and then only update the state if this attribute is not set. For example:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unmounted = true;
}

...

someMethod() {
  if (!this.unmounted) this.setState{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to resolve this issue it as follows

```
class X extends Component {
  mounted = false 
  ss = (...args) => {
    this.mounted && this.setState(...args)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.mounted = true 
  }
  componentWillUnMount(){ // or componentDidUnmount
    this.mounted = false 
  }
}
```

now you can use `this.ss` instead of `this.setState` or alternatively you can check the `this.mounted` before setting the state

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it does resolve the issue

Comment: About whether it's the best solution to this or not, I've gone back and forth about it and ended up being ok with it. My reasoning is that when you do async operations on a Component you are already veering away from React world and this is a good solution to that problem. Nothing wrong with checking that the component is still mounted before attempting to perform a set state operation!